# Python escape "{}" symbol

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a string in which i am using string formatting:

`'SELECT {} FROM {} WHERE country={} AND \{\}'.format("apples", "tables","home")`

Currently this doesnt work though; How to escape the { and } so that the string prints:

```
SELECT apples FROM tables WHERE country=home AND {}
```

?

Comment: Briefly: double them.

Comment: How about `'SELECT {} FROM {} WHERE country={} AND {}'.format("apples", "tables","home", "{}")` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can escape the `{}` sequence by using `{{}}`:

```
>>> 'SELECT {} FROM {} WHERE country={} AND {{}}'.format("apples", "tables","home")
'SELECT apples FROM tables WHERE country=home AND {}'
```